# How to increase Laravel speed?

Tags: laravel, performance, pagespeed

I will make a website using Laravel as frontend and Golang as Backend. I use ElasticSearch as a database that is accessed directly by golang and MySQL as backups. Target website this is schools in Indonesia with potential users more than 5 million.

This is certainly because some forums complain about the performance of laravel speed.

My question is the best practice for this condition? Should I use Redis or the like? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enhance Artisan Command Uses
2. Remove Unused Service
3. Minimize Use of Plugins Laravel Developer
4. Profiling Your Queries
5. Apply “Eager Loading” to Your Data Laravel Developer
6. Precompile Assets
7. JIT Compiler

for more information go to [here](https://dzone.com/articles/7-performance-optimization-tips-for-your-laravel-d) link

Comment: Looks like this is very complete, thanks to the response, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redis to cache the HTML of the site.
I had similar issue, what I did was cache the html content of the page some time on redis. Also used cron job to refresh the cache regularly. The process may differ as your site seems to have more feature of search and all.
Use redis to cache the content and search results.
You can also cache css, js or any resource files using other features such as cloudflare cache.
[Here](http://sauravkc.com.np/blog/caching-laravel-site-using-redis) is what I did with my site. You can find a example of caching a single page in the link.

Comment: Also use eager loading and don't just pull the related models inside loop in you view.

Comment: Ok i see, it seems like installing the cache is also a good choice. So far I know Redis just to keep key: value only. Thanks to the links, very helpful.

Comment: Ok i see, it seems like installing the cache is also a good choice. So far I know Redis just to keep key: value only. Thanks to the links, very helpful.